# Removing duplicates from a list in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, duplicates

Here is my code for displaying data from my db as a dropdown list. I'm looking for a way to remove duplicates so that only one instance of each is displayed. Anyone know a simple way of doing this?

```
@model IEnumerable<bookingsMVC.Models.member>
<select id="myTown">

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {

  <option id="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.town)" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.town)"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.town)</option>


 }
</select>
```

Model:

```
namespace bookingsMVC.Models
{
public class member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string address1 { get; set; }
    public string address2 { get; set; }
    public string town { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }     
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string memcat { get; set; }
    public string Admin { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show your model definition, your action method and the view's @model declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, to retain the full `Item` object, you can use `GroupBy` with `First()` to retrieve the first of each group:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(m => m.town).Select(g => g.First()))
...
```

Comment: Thanks this wors! Do you know a way to make in work where duplicates are not case sensitive?

Comment: ? `GroupBy(m => m.town.ToLower())`. It will be a random-case town returned, unless you do an `OrderBy` before the `.First()`

Answer (score 2):

you may want to do this in your controller and manage the actual filtering by distinct town there and that way you can simply pass the list with distinct town values to your viewmodel

Comment: here it is List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList(); yes use .distinct and it will work